What will be the benefits of having a hybrid SharePoint between (SharePoint online & SharePoint subscription server edition)
I am working on a new project where the customer has E5 licenses. So, they have 3 options for using SharePoint: -

Online only
On-premises only
Hybrid

This is the first time the customer will be using SharePoint, and we need to build this basic setup for phase one: -

Home site for all users, to access company-wide News/Announcements & company-wide Templates/Documents.
The home site will have links to each department site.
Each department site will have its own News/Announcement and Templates/Documents.
We will start by 3 departments: HR, IT & Finance.

We need to decide if we should go with SharePoint Online only, on-premises only or build a hybrid environment?
I am suggesting these Points/Approach:-

Since we need a basic setup and there are not any compliance requirements to use on-premises, we can do all the above inside SharePoint Online.
in the future if certain departments have specific compliances requirements, we can set up the SharePoint subscription server edition and build a hybrid environment with the available online

Can anyone advice on which approach to follow? and does my suggested approach makes sense?
Thanks

Your suggested approach is definitely the best.
For the setup you mentioned, with no additional requirements, SharePoint Online is the optimal solution.
However, consider this:

When will you know the additional compliance requirements? In a month? In 5 years? If it's 5 years, it makes sense to redesign the solution later. If one month, it makes sense to speed up the requirements gathering.

Do NOT underestimate the effort, initial setup and adoption will take. Any change that big later may double that effort.

What do the similar companies in your sector decide for? Use those stereotypes. E.g. if my customer is a bank, I am mentally prepared for SharePoint Server - that's typical for the sector (but there are exceptions).  If I have a cozy family firm with 50 people - SharePoint Online, they don't want to bother too much with all the IT and infrastructure stuff.

Do you have any existing infrastructure? How do you connect it? How do you integrate it? Any on prem apps? Anything you need to migrate?  If you are starting from zero - SharePoint Online.

Some of the compliance requirements can be also managed in SharePoint Online - data residency with GEO Location, etc. Even when some weird requirements pop up - check for the possibilities in SharePoint Online. They are constantly updated and improved



Thanks for the helpful reply. Yes i think i will start with SharePoint online, but later on we might have SharePoint server (hybrid mainly).. but for now starting with SharePoint online will not need any further consideration from my side?, i mean whether we will have a hybrid solution in the future or not, there is not anything to do on the SharePoint online inside for now? i am correct?

Be very careful when you choose the domain .onmicrosoft.com - you can't change that. You will be stuck with users seeing in their every SPO website address whatever you chose.   Be very careful with the language you choose when setting up the tenant. It has repercussions all over the place and some of them require tremendous effort to set back (in SPO, in Power Platform). Some of them keep biting back for years.

yes i know those points very well.. as i set lot of tenants already.. but this is not my main question

There is nothing that comes to my head. Hybrid connectivity, hybrid search - it all should be fine.  Do you already have AD on prem? What's the status for Exchange? If they went/ are going on a similar journey, I'd sync with your EXO Team to make sure they don't have any requirements that may affect you.

Make also sure the potential hybrid scenario is clear for your Identity Team so that they don't recreate your SPO user profiles by deleting and recreating/disabling and enabling user accounts when Entra ID Connect comes and they decide they want to to move users on prem (it's hard for me to say what their plan might be with the little I know about your company, it's an unlikely but a bad scenario)

I think i am overthinking the case .. i will just start with SPO online and connect to it an on-premises server if/when needed...

Hybrid setup is really tricky. It would require advanced SharePoint skills. So if you are just starting SharePoint - I'd recommend online only setup.

i have 12 years of experience in SharePoint. online and on-premises (starting from version 2010 till 2016) but never used hybrid before

I supported hybrid with one of my clients for ~2-3 years, we were having issues with User Profiles and Search, also with our network security (proxy). Not sure if it's possible, but maybe you can try hybrid with SharePoint on-prem trial version and m365 dev environment...
